# How to assign different weights to scores from multiple fields in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I want to make a query on multiple fields in Lucene 4.6. I have two fields -- title and body. I want to give more weights the title than to the body field for a specific query, for example in 0.7 to 0.3 split. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Field.setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Field.html#setBoost%28float%29), at index time,

Or just give the terms a boost at query time, using [Query.setBoost](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Query.html#setBoost%28float%29), or through the [query parser syntax](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#Boosting_a_Term)